# Statistics based on fractal mathematics

Tags: references, fractal

I am looking for books / textbooks on statistics based on fractal mathematics. I know it is not a very well known area and it is rather difficult to find good literature. Any suggestions are welcome (books, textbooks, online materials).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- [Tutorials in Contemporary Nonlinear Methods for the Behavioral Sciences Web Book](http://www.nsf.gov/sbe/bcs/pac/nmbs/nmbs.jsp)

It has several chapters discussing fractals.

Comment: Nice book!